# css bootstrap flexbox размер

Tags: css, bootstrap, flexbox

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы панель nav занимала меньше места на экране. На большом экране занимает почти весь экран

```
<div id="main">
<article></article>  
<nav>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
         <?php
           $cat = new Categorie();
           $cat -> afficher_categories();
         ?>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>  
 </div>
</div>
   </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: Какой именно экран интересует ? пиксели. У вас же есть класс `container` он занимаем около 60% с цетровкой (там конкретные размеры прописаны по медиазапросам)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц более 1500px в ширину

Comment: вам подойдет просто уменьшение контейнера? `<div class="container w-xl-75">` либо если нужно именно `nav` - `<nav class=" w-xl-75 m-auto">`